# using boto and SES, emails with links don't go through

Tags: boto, amazon-ses

Something really weird is going on with boto and Amazon SES.  I've tested this at-least 50 times: Sending an email using:

```
conn = SESConnection(accessKey, secretKey)
conn.send_email(source=fromEmail, subject=subject, body=body, to_addresses=toAddress, cc_addresses=cc_addresses, bcc_addresses=bcc_addresses, format='html', reply_addresses=None, return_path=None)
```

works as long as the body is regular text.  A soon as `body` contains a link, like "127.0.0.1", the email doesn't go through.  `send_email` doesn't return an error, it just doesn't go through and I can't tell why.  The only exception is if the link is the very last piece of text in the body.  So, `body = "go to 127.0.0.1"` will get into the recipients' inboxes, but `body = "go to 127.0.0.1 and click on the link"` will not work.

Weird, right?  What's going on?

EDIT, several wasted hours later:
So after killing several hours on this, I don't know exactly what the problem is, but I know that it doesn't have to do with Boto or Amazon SES.  I sent the exact same email to a different address and had no problems with it.  Now this is seriously weird and stupid.  The email used for my school runs on Google apps and exhibits the wacky behavior described above.  My personal email is plain old gmail and doesn't have this issue at all.  I even checked the spam folder for my school email and it's not there.

So that's it, the difference between having an "http" and an "https" in the body of the email, and only for certain email accounts.  No errors, just a lost email.  WTF?